# Winforms Gridview Calculation

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have 2 columns so when the first column cell value contains "ok" then a calculation will be done on the second column. If it does not contain "ok" then I don't need any calculation.

The code works but does not depend on "ok", it doesn't matter if the cell contains "ok" or whatever else.

```
private void calculate()
{
    if (gridView3.Columns["Status"] == gridView3.GetFocusedRowCellValue("ok"))
    {
        gridColumn3.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
        gridColumn3.UnboundExpression = "DateDiffDay([StartDate], LocalDateTimeToday())";
    }
    else
    {   

    }
}
```

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" is not useful. Which bit doesn't work? What actually happens? Is there an error? What steps have you taken to fix it?

Comment: works but not depends on ok.. doesnt matter cell contains ok or whatelse

Comment: Looks like you're setting the `UnboundExpression` of the _column_, so if the condition in your `if` statement matches _at least once_, the expression is applied to all cells in that column.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the **UnboundExpression** property influences a whole unbound column. If you need to calculate values only for particular rows, it is necessary to leave the UnboundExpression property empty and handle the [GridView.CustomUnboundColumnData](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData.event) event. This event is raised for each row allowing you to calculate values for the required rows.

Answer (score 1):

You should either build the [correct unbound expression](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/6214/Common-Features/Expressions/Expression-Operators-Functions-and-Constants):

```
gridColumn3.UnboundExpression = "Iif([Status]=1, DateDiffDay([StartDate], LocalDateTimeToday()), 0)";
```

or handle the [GridView.CustomUnboundColumnData](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData.event) event as follows:

```
gridColumn3.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
gridView1.CustomUnboundColumnData += gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData;
// ...
void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e) {
    ColumnView view = ((ColumnView)sender);
    if(e.IsGetData && e.Column == gridColumn3) 
        e.Value = DateTime.Now.Day - ((EventObj)e.Row).StartDate.Day;
}
// ...
public enum Status { 
    Unknown, Ok 
}
public class EventObj {
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```